# Estimating standard deviation when observing means of various block sizes

Tags: unbiased-estimator, point-estimation

I have a sequence $X_i$ of iid random variables (you may assume gaussian distribution if you like) but I only observe the mean value of disjoint blocks of various sizes of $X_i$. E.g. $M_1 = \frac14 \sum_{i=1}^4 X_i$, $M_2 = \frac17 \sum_{i=5}^{11} X_i$, $M_3 = \frac17 \sum_{i=12}^{18}$ etc.

In my case the blocks are weeks, and I get the result for each week in a month, the first and last week are not full 7-day weeks, but the weeks in between are full 7-day weeks.

Now, I would like to estimate the mean, $\mu$, and standard deviation, $\sigma$, of $X_i$.

My thoughts are that $M_j$ will have the same mean, $\mu$, as $X_i$ but the standard deviation of $M_j$ are $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n_j}}$ where $n_j$ is the number of $X_i$ that are included the mean $M_j$.

Now, if I have a sample $m_j$ of $M_j$, I could calculate the weighted sample mean
$\hat m = \frac{\sum n_j m_j}{\sum n_j}$
I would have
$n_j (m_j - \hat m)^2$ with expected value $\sigma^2$ and I could take a weighted mean to get an estimate $s^2$ of $\sigma^2$ as
$s^2 = \frac{\sum n_j^2 (m_j-\hat m)^2}{\sum n_j}$

Now, for a small number of blocks this estimate is biased, so I would need some kind of Bessel like correction.

I tried with
$s^2 = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^k n_j^2 (m_j-\hat m)^2}{\sum_{j=1}^k n_j} \cdot \frac{k}{k-1}$
but when simulating with R I still get a bias:

```
rm(.Random.seed)
wdays = c(4,rep(7,2))
totdays = sum(wdays)
nweeks = length(wdays)
sz = 160000
means = vector('numeric',length = sz)
stdevs = vector('numeric',length = sz)
m = vector('numeric',length = nweeks)
for(i in 1:sz){
  tot = 0
  for(j in 1:nweeks){
    y = rnorm(wdays[j],7000,1000)
    m[j] = mean(y)
    tot = tot + sum(y)
  }
  my = tot/totdays
  sd_est = sqrt( sum(wdays^2*(m-my)^2) / totdays * nweeks/(nweeks-1) )
  means[i] = my
  stdevs[i] = sd_est
}
gm = mean(means)
gmSE = sd(means)/sqrt(sz)
print(c(gm-1.96*gmSE,gm+1.96*gmSE))
print(sd(means))
print(sd(means)*sqrt(totdays))
gsd = sqrt(mean(stdevs^2))
gsdSE = sd(stdevs)/sqrt(sz)
print(c(gsd-1.96*gsdSE,gsd+1.96*gsdSE))
print(sd(stdevs))
```

With result:

```
R -f sdest.R --slave
[1] 6998.517 7000.826
[1] 235.6361
[1] 999.7193
[1] 983.5193 988.0404
[1] 461.3369
```

While unweighted estimate

```
  sd_est = sqrt( sum(wdays*(m-my)^2) / (nweeks-1) )
```

would be unbiased:

```
R -f sdest.R --slave
[1] 6997.726 7000.041
[1] 236.2924
[1] 1002.504
[1]  997.4402 1001.9852
[1] 463.7799
```

Now, my question is, for the weighted estimate, what's the correct way to do a Bessel like correction to remove the bias?

Or is it a bad idea to do a weighted estimate of the standard deviation?

Comment: Bias is probably a tertiary concern (and easily dealt with).  Foremost ought to be the possibility of serial correlation (over time) and lack of stationarity (that is, changes in the parameters over time).  What have you done to assess these?

Comment: Serial correlation would be correlation between the $M_i$, right? From the sampling procedure I would say that they are uncorrelated (independent even). The lack of stationarity is likely a real concern, but I only have three samples so far (but for 13 subjects, i.e. three samples for each). I haven't done anything to assess that yet. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: The question is based on an idealized situation as described in the model. The actual situation is probably not really amenable to statistical analysis and just a hobby project, but it sparked the question, how should one really do the estimate of standard deviation when having averages of different sizes.

Comment: The latter is the subject of Analysis of Variance, or [ANOVA (*q.v.*)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anova).

Answer (score 0):

$Var(X_i)=\sigma^2$, $Var(M_j) = Var(\sum _{i=1}^{n_j} X_i) = n_j\sigma^2 $

$Var(\sqrt {n_j}M_j) = \sigma^2$

Let $Y_j = \sqrt {n_j}M_j$, the sample variance defined by 
$s^2 = \frac 1 {k-1}\sum_{j=1}^k (Y_j - \bar Y)^2$
will be unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$.

$s$ is still biased estimate of $\sigma$.

Based on your program, I added my method, the final result is 1000.712 (vs 1000).

```
rm(.Random.seed)
wdays = c(4,rep(7,2))
totdays = sum(wdays)
nweeks = length(wdays)
sz = 160000
means = vector('numeric',length = sz)
newy = vector('numeric',length = sz)
stdevs = vector('numeric',length = sz)
m = vector('numeric',length = nweeks)
mm = vector('numeric',length = nweeks)
for(i in 1:sz){
  tot = 0
  for(j in 1:nweeks){
    y = rnorm(wdays[j],7000,1000)
    m[j] = mean(y)
    mm[j] = m[j]*sqrt(wdays[j])
    tot = tot + sum(y)
  }
  my = tot/totdays
  sd_est = sqrt( sum(wdays^2*(m-my)^2) / totdays * nweeks/(nweeks-1) )
  means[i] = my
  newy[i]=mm
  stdevs[i] = sd_est
}
sd(newy)
```

Result is 1000.712.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying with your answer. It this just a confirmation that my unweighted estimate is unbiased? What about doing a weighted estimate then? Not a good idea? Intuitively the standard deviation of the short weeks should be larger than the full weeks, no need to take that into account?

Comment: In your question, you said your estimate is biased. So I gave you an unbiased. You can add my estimate in your simulation program, to see if it biased or not.

Comment: Yes, the first estimate (weighted) is biased and the question was how to make it unbiased. The second estimate (unweighted) is unbiased and if I understand your answer correctly is identical to what you suggest, I assume you mean $\sqrt{n_j}$ and not $\sqrt{n}$ for the total mean also. Otherwise the estimate will be way off.

Comment: The answer is edited. This time I think you know how to add this part into your simulation.